# (ARDUINO) About Port Manipulation

Tags: c, arduino

I am making a 16-bit decimal to binary converter with 8 leds using port manipulation. User enters the decimal then program converts it to binary then writes the leds. But I have a problem with port manipulation. I keep binary number as a type of String so I can't write number to pins. My code is;

```
void setup() {
DDRC = B11111111;
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
if(Serial.available()>0){
long input = Serial.parseInt();
 if (input>=2){  
 y = input/2;
    while (y>0){
        r = input % 2;
        out = String(r) + out;
        y = input/2;
        input = y ;
        }}
else
        out = String(input); 
int digits = out.length();

 for(int i=0; i<(16-digits); i++){
 out = "0" + out;
  }
  String firstEight = "B" + out.substring(0,8);
 String lastEight = "B" + out.substring(8,16);
```

Then I add this line end of the code

PORTC = firstEight;

and I get this error message: cannot convert 'String' to 'volatile uint8_t {aka volatile unsigned char}' in assignment
Sorry if this is actually a common knowledge, but I couldn't find it.

This is my homework so i have to convert decimal to binary with my own code. that is why i use the String. It keeps the bits of binary.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `B*` are macros provided by the Arduino libraries and can't be used in the manner that you are trying to do so. What you should be doing is taking `input`, masking the bits you need, and outputting that number to the port.

```
PORTC = (input >> 8); // 8 leftmost bits in the parsed int
```